# Javascript script gives error "TypeError: n is undefined"

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have created a javascript script to do something, and mostly it worked. There are two issues I had with the script, so I planned to put a working example here on SO. However, during the 'reduction' of the code to something less complex a third error occurred, which completely made the script stop working. Here is the javascript part of the script:

```
var container, stats;
var camera, scene, renderer;
var group1, group2;
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
var map_width = 512;
var map_height = 512; 

var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

init();
animate();

function createMesh(filename) {

    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 70, 40, 40 );
    var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader(filename);
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, overdraw: 0.5 } );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    return mesh;
}


function init() {

    container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
    camera.position.z = 500;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();                                             

    group1 = new THREE.Group();    
    var mesh = createMesh("textures/tree1.jpg");
    group1.add( mesh );
    group1.position.x = 00;                
    scene.add( group1 );                

    group2 = new THREE.Group();    
    var mesh = createMesh("textures/tree2.jpg");
    group2.add( mesh );
    group2.position.x = 250;                
    scene.add( group2 );                            

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
    renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 0 );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
}


function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
}

function render() {
    camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.05;
    camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * 0.05;
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

    group1.rotation.y -= 0.005;
    group2.rotation.y -= 0.015;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

The idea is to have several spheres with some texture on it; to try just use any image. However, when I call this code within a html I get the error

TypeError: `n is undefined`

all over again. The error seems to originate in `THREE.js`. How can I fix this error, so I see two spheres with a 'tree' texture on it...?

The body of the html code is as follows:

```
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="js/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        >> the code from above <<
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: It's almost impossible to diagnose this with the information provided. The error you describe essentially says "you haven't said what one of your values should be". If you are able to post a more complete example, perhaps on something like jsfiddle, it will be easier to help.

Comment: There is no `n` variable in your code.

Comment: The above is the COMPLETE javascript code. I know there is no variable 'n' in this code. I can post the html code as well if you need...

Comment: And where the error is getting hit? which line in above code?

Comment: three.min.js line 553

Comment: Are you sure you minified it correctly? There typically 1 line in minified files, not 533? Can you try to reproduce with not minified three?

Comment: Now I get the error `offset is undefined` in line 21482.

Comment: Maybe I am using a buggy version of `three.js`?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by the following line:

```
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader(filename);
```

The solution is to use a `loader` instead:

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texture = loader.load( filename );
```

Comment: How did you find this to be the cause? I'm trying to debug the same error, but my code is very different, so I'm interested in your technique.